# jCarousel Auto Scroll On Button Click

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

How do I modify this jCarousel example so that when the left or right button is clicked, the carousel will continually scroll in that direction: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html.

At the moment, the example cancels the automatic scrolling once any of the buttons are clicked which is something I want to avoid.

I am quite new to jCarousel and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like jCarousel has built in support for automatic scrolling in reverse.

In order to do this, I had to modify the `startAuto` function to accept negative numbers.  Then, when it got a negative number, it scrolls the other way automatically.

I also updated the click events on the next/previous buttons to call startAuto with the negative value if it is currently scrolling in the other direction.

Code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/28uph9g5/

Comment: Ah cool! That works really well! Thanks for the effort I was really stumped. I just have one more query. In my own example, I am using external anchor tags to go left and right. So I modified your example to bind the clicks but for some reason they are not firing straight away. I need to click on the left and right links a few times to fire.

Comment: You need to bind your external anchors to the carousel prev/next functions as well.  Here: http://jsfiddle.net/ms2hp/  Look in the carousel callback for "EXTERNAL LINKS HERE".

Comment: Ah great thanks. I think I was binding it incorrectly by having using "jQuery" keyword instead of "$". Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Hmm, jQuery and $ should usually be interchangeable, but glad you got it to work!

Comment: above link is not working correctly. can you check it please?

Comment: @Sarower: jCarousel has changed quite a bit since this question was asked.  For instance, it now handles autoscrolling with a plugin (jCarouselAutoscroll), which handles reverse scrolling, via the option 'target':  `target: '-=1'`.  I would suggest looking for something specific to the newer versions.

Comment: I fixed it for the old version, so it works, but I will still recommend a newer version.